# TensorFlow training with Supervisor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using `managed_session` to train a TensorFlow model. The main loop looks like this:

```
  if FLAGS.train:
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.training_dir,
                           checkpoint_basename='mymodel',
                           save_model_secs=30,
                           save_summaries_secs=20,
                           summary_op = model.all_sums)
    with sv.managed_session() as sess:
      model.train(sess,FLAGS)
```

On running the training, the `mymodel` checkpoint file and the `tfevents` files are **created**. However neither the events files, nor the checkpoint file is **updated**. TensorBoard understandably complains that it can't find any scalars.
I don't have a `global_step` variable in the model.
Any ideas what could be going wrong or how to debug?

**Note:** The same code works when I use simple `tf.Session` and manually write to the `tfevents` file using `tf.summary.FileWriter().add_summary()`.

Comment: Sorry to ask a stupid question, but did you add some scalar summary using for example `tf.summary.scalar('my_scalar_tensor', my_scalar_tensor)`? Also it would help if you could provide a self-contained example.

Comment: Yes, I added a bunch of summaries... while using `tf.Session()` I run the summary_op, and add the summary to writer and it works fine. I don't run the summary_op while using `managed_session()`  though.